# select <option> and change val() useing jquery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#test').val() == 1) {
    var gg = 120;
    $('#first').val(gg);
    $('#two').val(gg);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="test" required>
  <option value="1" selected>OK</option>
  <option value="2">NO</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="first" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="two" class="form-control">
```

When i select OK i want to put into inputs 120. How can i do it? I try like this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `change` event to bind this like the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').change(function() {
    var gg = 130 - (this.value * 10);
    $('#first').val(gg);
    $('#two').val(gg);
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="test" required>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="first" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="two" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Exellent and  change to 110 when i select 'NO'

Comment: so if i have values from 1 to 5 i can just add 120 : 110 :100 : 90 : 80?

Comment: @Pompero of course, use something like `gg = 130 - (this.value * 10)`.